# Getting content from MYSQL's table continuously

Tags: java, mysql, sql, activemq-classic

I've a code here. My code works to getting every row's content (int) on a table and sent it to ActiveMQ continuously. When the table updated, then the new row's content will be sent to ActiveMQ.

But when i stopping the process and re-run again, it will sending all the content from row 0-all to the ActiveMQ. I wish i can make it just continuously sending the content that it wasn't sent before and works normally as usual again...

I think i must creating a new db table to save every last limit (row counting number) on the looping, so i can use it again when the process stopped. Any help?

```
else if(vardbtype.equals("MYSQL")){
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      System.out.println("----------------------------");
      int limitrowmysql = 0;
      Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+ vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
      while(true) {
          Statement stmts = c.createStatement();
          int countrowmysql = 0;
          String sql = ("SELECT * FROM "+ vardbname +" LIMIT "+ limitrowmysql +", 18446744073709551615");
          ResultSet rss = stmts.executeQuery(sql);
          while(rss.next()) {
              String  message = rss.getString("MESSAGE");
              System.out.println("Message = " + message);
              TextMessage mssg = session.createTextMessage(message);
              System.out.println("Sent: " + mssg.getText());
              producer.send(mssg);
              countrowmysql = countrowmysql + 1;
          }
          rss.close();
          stmts.close();

          limitrowmysql = limitrowmysql + countrowmysql;
          Thread.sleep(batchperiod2);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you will need to handle the last-seen id yourself, or leverage a framework that handles this for you.

FYI-- The pattern you are looking for is often called a "Polling Consumer". Apache Camel has code to automatically handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my opinion is concerned, maintaining new table to save "row counting number" would not solve your problem. Consider the case when the process is down and any row has been Deleted/Updated by some other user(In case of multi-user application), storing "row counting number" would not help you out.

In Fact, You should rely upon the polling mechanism(Direct RMI/API/Method call) to fetch all the records from the DB in a single go at the time of process startup and follow the notification mechanism(ActiveMQ) henceforth for each and every update on the table, as you are already doing.

Comment: You are correct, that collecting updates are important, but the only way to collect that is to understand the structure of the table (record update field or timestamp), or to use the database's built in trigger or logging to craft events. I was not suggesting a "row counting", but a record identifier. However, polling the full table or database doesn't scale and is very resource intensive on the db side and the middleware. This also requires the middleware to track and filter "already seen data".